# Summing time series with slight variance in timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I imagine that I have several time series like following, from different "sources":

```
       time     events
0      1000    1080000
1      2003    2122386
2      3007    3043985
3      4007    3872544
4      5007    4853763
```

Here, an monotonic increasing count *events* is sampled every 1000 ms. The sampling is not *exact* so most of the timestamps vary from their ideal values by a few ms - e.g., the second point is at 2003 instead of 2000.

I want to *sum* several of these time series: they will all be sampled at ~1000 ms but may not agree to the exact millsecond. E.g another time series could be:

```
       time     events
0      1000    1070000
1      2002    2122486
2      3006    3063985
3      4007    3872544
4      5009    4853763
```

I'd like something *reasonable* in terms of the final result. For example the same number of rows as each of the input dataframes, with a timestamp column the same as the first, or average of the inputs times. As long as the inputs are smooth, the outputs should be too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [DataFrame.reindex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with nearest method. Example:

```
def combine_datasources(reference_df, extra_dfs, tolerance_ms=100):
    reindexed_df_list = [df.reindex(reference_df.index, method='nearest', tolerance=tolerance_ms) for df in extra_dfs]
    combined = pd.concat([reference_df, *reindexed_df_list])
    return combined.groupby(combined.index).sum()

combine_datasources(df_a, [df_b])
```

This code changes the index on the dataframes in the extra_dfs list to match the index for the reference dataframe. Then, it concatenates all of the dataframes together. It uses groupby to do the sum, which requires that the indexes match exactly to work. The timestamps will be the same as the one on the reference dataframe.

Note that if you have data from a time period not covered by the reference dataframe, that data will be dropped.

Here's the output for the dataset in your question:

```
       events
time         
1000  2150000
2003  4244872
3007  6107970
4007  7745088
5007  9707526
```